# Is GNU gettext built in into Wordpress or do I have to download it separately?

Tags: wordpress, gettext

Is GNU gettext built in into Wordpress or do I have to download it separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [built into WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#Localization_Technology) as the localization framework.